# Nginx If statement executed before location?

Tags: nginx

I'm confused why nginx is executing my If statement "before" the location statement.
More precise, why is nginx not executing the return statement and then stops processing?

I would expect if I open /xyz to get a 200 with "hello world" even if $http_x_forwarded_host is not [www.acme.com](http://www.acme.com) because the if statement is located down the location statement. But nginx just ignor the location statement and ran into the if clause. Any ideas? I tried `break;` with no luck.

```
    server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index   index.html index.htm index.php;
    
        location /xyz {
          return 200 'hello world';

        }

        if ($http_x_forwarded_host != "www.acme.com") {
                return 301 https://www.acme.com$uri;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, all directives from the [`ngx_http_rewrite_module`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) are executed **before** the location selection mechanism took its place. Using the `break` directive means breaking the execution of those directives from the rewrite module and immediately force the request execution according to the best matching location. This happened because although nginx configuration in general is declarative, rewrite module evaluates its instructions imperatively. This is always a source of confusion for every nginx novice. You can read more about the rewrite module internal implementation [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#internals).

Being that said, you can't implement that sort of behavior with your configuration. It doesn't mean you can't achieve what you want at all, one of possible solutions is to use the regex negative lookahead feature:

```
    if ($http_x_forwarded_host != "www.acme.com") {
        # do the redirect only if the URI doesn't start with '/xyz'
        rewrite ^(?!/xyz) https://www.acme.com$uri permanent;
    }
    location /xyz {
        return 200 'hello world';
    }
```

If you want to do some complex request processing instead of redirection, you can use an [`internal`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal) location:

```
    if ($http_x_forwarded_host != "www.acme.com") {
        # in case you will need an original URI later, you can save its value
        # set $original_uri $uri;
        # process the request with the special location only if the URI doesn't start with '/xyz'
        rewrite ^(?!/xyz) /special;
    }
    location /xyz {
        return 200 'hello world';
    }
    location /special {
        internal;
        ... # any custom processing here, for example 'return 403;'
    }
```

It should be obvious that for such a locations you should choose an URI prefix than can't interfere with your existing site in any ways.

Comment: Thank you @Ivan I will try that and give feedback.

Comment: Worked fine. Do you know if it is possibe to do the same logic but send an 403 instead of an redirect. But the !/xyz exception should stay there. I cant find a way because "return 403" does not take RegEx.

Comment: Thank you Ivan - that worked like charm for me. Great Answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because after the redirection it reaches your site again. Maybe the redirection is pointing to the same host as the location?